# Pandas DataFrame.to_excel How to ignore Formula

Tags: python, excel, pandas

First of all i looked on the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), on stackoverflow and google. I did not find anything that really helps me so i decided to post a question, if i miss someone who had the same problem, i apologize.

this is my problem, i have a df named `parameters` which is like that :

```
     attribute            clause      value
0    distinguishedName    like       (.)*=_FR,DC=HLD, DC=NET
1    Institution_Label    ==         FakeCompanyName Inc.
2    Employee_Type        ==         1   
3    Email               not like    (.)*.deleted
```

and i use the pandas function to_excel to write it in an xlsx file. it creates the file but it replaces the == with 0 in the xlsx file because i think it detects the string like an excel Formula. Do you know if it is possible to ignore that ?

To fix my problem, i add a ' before the == so excel doesn't transform it. It's works. Now i have a '== in my excel file instead of 0, but what i really want is a ==

Does anybody know a better way to ignore the formula without having to change the value of the dataframe's cell please ?

Here's my code :

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Exportations\\DDLCard_"+DDLName+".xlsx")

#replace the == with '==
parameters["clause"] = parameters["clause"].apply(transformParametersClauseToIgnoreExcelFormula)


list_dfs = {}
list_dfs["parameters"] = parameters
#we don't care about those DF
list_dfs["df2"] = df2
list_dfs["df3"] = df2
list_dfs["df4"] = df2


#foreach df, write it on the xlsx file on the sheet named "key"
for key, df in list_dfs.items():
    df.to_excel(writer,
        sheet_name = key,
        encoding = "utf-8",
        index = False
    )
    writer.sheets[key].set_column('A:CO', 25)
writer.save()


def transformParametersClauseToIgnoreExcelFormula(value):
    return re.sub(r"==","'==",value)
```

Thank you !

PS : forgive me if i made any mistakes, English is not my mother tongue language

Comment: Would you consider converting it to a csv instead?

Comment: I can't,  in the "list_dfs", i have a list of Dataframes and i put each df in a different sheet. csv file can't have sheet.

In fact, i could do an export of these dataframes in different csv files (some of these DF are in csv files btw), but the xlsx file is kind of a synthesis of all the information on one subject.
thanks for the answer tho ! :)

Comment: The equal signs are very important in Excel cells. There may be no way around it. As @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ suggests, try saving as text files or database tables (SQLite and MS Access are file-level dbs) and store all values as strings. And yes, pandas can connect to RDBMS's.

Comment: okay, well i think i'm just going to put some "" around the == so excel won't detect the equal sign if there is no better way. it's still "works" and it's understandable. I'm surprised that no one had the problem before though.
Thanks for your help Coldspeed and Parfait.

Comment: The issue is excel, not Python. Python writes the value correct but if you type manually == into a excel cell and press enter you will notice that excel has a "problem" with this expression and wants to correct it to '==

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but for anyone else who finds this (depending on your exact use case), you could use this to your advantage by setting the string you want exported into Excel *as a formula*.

For example:

```
val = '=CONCATENATE("=")'
```

Would then display just = within Excel.

[image: Example screenshot of Excel with formulation bar and displayed value]